# Deploying a javaFx Application

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am using Sbt, with the plugins Sbt Assembly. What it does is that it create a fat jar that contain everything my project depends which in this case include, Jfxrt.jar.

Given that i want my app to run on windows as well, i was wondering if that was a problem. Does the Jfxrt.jar for OsX and windows are the same ?

The question could be extended to other platform of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is a problem, on win32 javafx uses directx and on other platforms OpenGL. Beside that the glass toolkit is different foreach platform. Do not package javafx with your application you would have never thought of this for a swing app so why do you do this for JavaFX.

So no the jar is different for each platform